# WCF security advice

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, wcf-security

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7 application, and to go with it I will need a web service to send out live tile push notifications. I will save the clients URI channel in a database and every hour or so I will send out the correct live tile to all the subscribed clients. I will not be sending out any sensitive data to the clients, nor do the clients send any data to the service save for their channel URI, and I've made sure to protect the database against any sql-injections.

The exposed methods are for registering and unregistering a client, as well as sending the correct live tile to a client that requests it.

Given this information, does anyone have any recommendations on how I should secure the service, or is security even needed to begin with in this case?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Thanks for the answers! My peers decided to not use any security at all though, other than purging faulty requests from the database, since the scope of the application is quite limited and no sensitive data is being transmitted. Let's hope it won't bite us in our behinds later on, eh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the best solution to this problem (at the moment) is to generate a hash in your app and use that to verify the data is really coming from your app. Obviously you'll need to obfuscate tyour code if doing this.

This is the best you can do without any authentication against the backend.

If you can, have the users register and authenticate with the backend and then tie this authentication token to the ANID of the device and do everything over SSL.

Unfortunately, currenlty, security of services and prevention of spoffed requests is quite tricky with WP7 without requiring a login to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you secure your channel to your backend service with SSL.  This way the data you send to the server such as a the ChannelUri will be secure.

Building a hash into your application isnt security.  People could get your XAP and decompile it to get the hash.

IMHO you are better to ensure your ChannelUri (unique to your app and not "stored" in your XAP anywhere) is secured when you send it.

On the backend just make sure you purge records that fail when you try and send it a tile notification.  This will get rid of any records entered by non-phone parties.

Bottom line is that you need a login infrastructure with your backend to properly ensure only valid users are using your service.